# jaxl return to function that it's called from

Tags: php, xmpp, xmpphp

I have library  for xmpp transactions used jaxl libraries:

```
    class xmpp{

        public function register_user($username, $password){
            require_once 'JAXL/jaxl.php';

            $this->client = new JAXL(array(
                'jid' => 'localhost',
                'log_level' => JAXL_ERROR
            ));         
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password;

            $this->client->require_xep(array(
                '0077'  // InBand Registration  
            ));     
            $thisClassObject =& $this;

            $this->client->add_cb('on_stream_features', function($stanza) use(&$thisClassObject) {
                $thisClassObject->client->xeps['0077']->get_form('localhost');
                return array($thisClassObject, 'wait_for_register_form');
            });

            $this->client->start();     

            return;
        }

        public function wait_for_register_response($event, $args) {


           if($event == 'end_stream') {
                return;
            }
            else if($event == 'stanza_cb') {
                $stanza = $args[0];
               if($stanza->name == 'iq') {
                if($stanza->attrs['type'] == 'result') {
                    echo "registration successful".PHP_EOL."shutting down...".PHP_EOL;
                    $this->client->end_stream();
                    return 'logged_out';
                }
                else if($stanza->attrs['type'] == 'error') {
                    $error = $stanza->exists('error');
                    echo "registration failed with error code: ".$error->attrs['code']." and type: ".$error->attrs['type'].PHP_EOL;
                    echo "error text: ".$error->exists('text')->text.PHP_EOL;
                    echo "shutting down...".PHP_EOL;
                    $this->client->end_stream();
                    return "logged_out";
                }
            }
        }
    }

         public function wait_for_register_form($event, $args) {

            $stanza = $args[0];
            $query = $stanza->exists('query', NS_INBAND_REGISTER);
            if($query) {
                $form = array();
                $instructions = $query->exists('instructions');
                if($instructions) {
                echo $instructions->text.PHP_EOL;
            }

            $this->client->xeps['0077']->set_form($stanza->attrs['from'], array('username' => $this->username, 'password' => $this->password));
            return array($this, "wait_for_register_response");
        }
        else {
            $this->client->end_stream();
            return "logged_out";
        }
       }    
   }
```

these code are same as register_user.php, but implemented in a class;

i use this class in my code in this way:

```
$xmppObj = new xmpp();
$xmppObj('user','password');
/*
 some more code after this
/*
```

when it execute , create user successfully but it's print a message ('registration successful ...') and application exited and it doesn't execute "some code after this" after the class function, in the other word it doesn't follow the code...

What can I do for solve this problem, a person can help me that familiar with JAXL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are pretty much using the same code as found inside [examples/register_user.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/register_user.php). Once user registration is successful, script closes [XMPPStream](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/xmpp/xmpp_stream.php) as evident from this section of the code:

```
if($stanza->attrs['type'] == 'result') {
    echo "registration successful".PHP_EOL."shutting down...".PHP_EOL;
    $this->client->end_stream();
    return 'logged_out';
}
```

You MUST instead call `$client->send_end_stream();` and not `$client->end_stream();`. This will make sure underlying XMPPStream makes proper [FSM state transition](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/core/jaxl_fsm.php). Also add a callback for `on_disconnect` event, inside this callback you can again try to connect back with newly registered XMPP account and it should just work fine.

**Note**: Kindly checkout latest code from the repository. I made some updates which will allow core JAXLLoop to be re-initialized. If you are interested in details, here is the [commit log](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/compare/2518a44b9dfe...cdc3f1711bcf).